# shell scripting time difference in variables

Tags: shell, time, scripting

How can i get the time difference in 2 variables in shell

```
say i have 4 variables-

    t1=07:50:19:612
    t2=07:52:14:697
    t3=10:20:54:201
    t4=11:02:09:716

 and i want to find difference in times
 result=(t2-t1)+(t4-t3)
```

Comment: what does the variables represent ?  I guess time.

Comment: it would be nice if i may get result in this format say 5hours, 25 minutes and 10 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If milliseconds can't be ignored, I suggest you to define own shell functions :

```
function getMillis()
{
     val=($(echo $1|grep -Eo "(00|[1-9][0-9]*)"))
     mil=$(( ${val[0]} * 3600000 ))
     mil=$(($mil + ${val[1]}*60000))
     mil=$(($mil + ${val[2]}*1000))
     mil=$(($mil + ${val[3]}))
     echo $mil
} 

function format()
{
     hr=$(( $1 / 3600000 ))
     mn=$(( $1 % 3600000 / 60000 ))
     sc=$(( $1 % 60000 / 1000 ))
     ms=$(( $1 % 1000 ))
     echo "$hr hours,  $mn mins, $sc secs, $ms millisecs"
}
```

Then you can obtain the desired result as :

```
res=$(( $(getMillis $t2) - $(getMillis $t1) + $(getMillis $t4) - $(getMillis $t3) ))
format $res
```

The code above is just to show how this can be done. There may be other elegant solutions present.

Comment: function getMillis  doesn't work for times like '07:00:19:000'

Comment: @user2432405 check now.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, shell do not support date format for millisecond. The command date can handle time format, of which the precision is rounded up to second.

The following is an example for time format with second as mininum time unit:

```
t1=07:50:19
t2=07:52:14
t3=10:20:54
t4=11:02:09

t10=$(date -d $t1 +%s)
t20=$(date -d $t2 +%s)
t30=$(date -d $t3 +%s)
t40=$(date -d $t4 +%s)

result=$(expr $t20 - $t10 + $t40 - $t30)
echo $result

hour=$(expr $result / 3600)
min=$(expr $result % 3600 / 60)
sec=$(expr $result % 60)

echo $hour:$min:$sec
```

Comment: @lulyon- Thanx for this code, but it shows 2590 as result, i want in hh:mm:ss, how can i get in that form?

Comment: @user2663468 That is the resulting seconds. See updated version of my answer.